# combination od 2 fields as composite key

Tags: trigger

```
trigger CheckDuplicate on Object_Configuaration__c (before insert,before update) {
        List<Object_Configuaration__c> StaActiList = [Select Name, Operations__c from Object_Configuaration__c ];  
for (Object_Configuaration__c staActnew : Trigger.new)
  {      
    for(Object_Configuaration__c sa: StaActiList)
        {         
               if(sa.Name== staActnew.Name && sa.Operations__c == staActnew.Operations__c )         
                  {   
                  system.debug('sa.Name== staActnew.Name'+  sa.Name+'=='+ staActnew.Name    );
                  system.debug(  'sa.Operations__c == staActnew.Operations__c '+  sa.Operations__c+''+staActnew.Operations__c );
                    staActnew.addError('Duplicate record ');        
                  }     
       } 
  }

    }
```

i want to restrict duplicates based on Name (standard field and Operation(pickliswt,custom field).suppose If Contact is Name and Create is selected from picklist,and if i enter Account and create it should save,but it is throwing error.[image],please help me how to do it.

Comment: i dont want to use work flow,because while creating packages,workflow will not work properly

Comment: What do you mean workflow will not work properly? Also if that's your only qualm you could easily build the key in an `Apex Trigger`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
trigger CheckDuplicate on Object_Configuaration__c (before insert,before update)
{
    List<Object_Configuaration__c> StaActiList = [SELECT ID,Operations__c,Object_Name__c, Name,Source_System_Configuaration__c, Source_System_Configuaration__r.id, Source_System_Configuaration__r.Name,Source_System_Configuaration__r.System_Id__c FROM Object_Configuaration__c];
    for (Object_Configuaration__c staActnew : Trigger.new)
    {
        for(Object_Configuaration__c sa: StaActiList)
        {
            if(sa.Object_Name__c== staActnew.Object_Name__c && sa.Operations__c == staActnew.Operations__c && sa.Source_System_Configuaration__c == staActnew.Source_System_Configuaration__c)
            {   
                staActnew.addError('Duplicate record ');
            }
        } 
    }
}
```